# IntelliJ Idea: How to create a custom inspection rule

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, code-inspection

I'm looking for the way to create inspection to warn about large non-javadoc comments in code.  I didn't found any suitable common inspection to do this. It looks like I should create a custom inspection rule. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: It is easier than you think, just look at the existing javadoc inspections in intellij-community source code and create a plugin with your own one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, there are two ways to create your own code inspection in IntelliJ IDEA:

1. *(simple but limited way)* Creating custom inspection based on "search templates".
2. *(more complex and more powerfull way)* Developing an IDEA-plugin (here are the [guidlines](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/plugin-development-guidelines.html)) using your own InspectionToolProvider implementation as "application-component". Also you may use sources of my [inspections-plugin](https://github.com/nolequen/idea-inspections-plugin) as the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

See http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Developing+Custom+Language+Plugins+for+IntelliJ+IDEA#DevelopingCustomLanguagePluginsforIntelliJIDEA-CodeInspectionsandIntentions. You can look at [Open API and Plugin Development forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development?view=discussions&start=0) for assistance.